# How to post to WordPress custom post type from ifttt.com

Tags: wordpress, if-this-then-that

I recently discovered ifttt.com and have been working on creating a few IFTTT tasks for my [Kansas City Royals website](http://crowncrazed.com). I am in the process of adding the ability for fans to make quick posts, such as YouTube videos, links, photos, etc.

These FanPosts are each a custom post type. I would like to set up a few feeds to post automatically to the custom post type "FanPost".

I love that IFTTT can automatically post to WordPress, but I do not want to post simple video embeds, links and photos to the main articles (Posts) section of the website, instead, I want to post to the custom post type(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the only way ifttt.com can post to Wordpress, is using the XML-RPC API, and that API currently doesn't support supplying custom post type while calling insert post methods(will support from 3.4), you can make use of the filter `wp_insert_post_data`. I accomplished that last month while building a hack. Here is a hack that would work the way you want, just add this to your `functions.php` file -

```
function redirect_xmlrpc_to_custom_post_type ($data, $postarr) {
    // This function detects a XML-RPC request and modifies it before posting

    $p2_custom_post_type = 'FanPost'; // Define your Custom post type

    if (defined('XMLRPC_REQUEST') || defined('APP_REQUEST')) {
        $data['post_type'] = $p2_custom_post_type; // sets the request post type to custom post type instead of the default 'Post'.
        return $data;
    }
    return $data;

}
// Add the filter
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'redirect_xmlrpc_to_custom_post_type', 99, 2);
```

Remember, this filter will detect *any* insert post request via the XML-RPC API and insert them to `FanPost` type. Be it from ifttt.com or anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question exactly as I asked, but I have a follow up question based on your answer. Is there a way to add multiple types of custom posts? I assume from your reply that it is not yet possible. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TravisPflanz Nope. I had to manually change this code and work every time I wanted to. For my case, I needed to import a bunch of data every time I ran the code. So manually editing worked for me.

Comment: WordPress 3.4 is here. Check out their API.

Comment: Just had a thought: you can specify what category your posts from IFTTT will be - what if you created a custom loop/styling based on the category chosen? `if ( $cat_from_ifttt = $category ) { //choose custom loop/styling? }` It's not exactly custom_post_types, but it's a possible workaround?

Comment: @Bibhas Is the 99, 2 in your code specific to your instance... or is the post_type = 'post_type_name' the only change necessary here? Thanks.